# apache CXF WebService annotation is not present on class

Tags: spring, web-services, cxf, java-ws

I using maven, Apache CXF with spring on weblogic 10.3.6 to expose Soap web service 
my web service depended on another web services client that i loaded as maven dependency

while i trying to call exposed web services i faced the below exception on client jar

```
A WebService annotation is not present on class: com.client.CustomerPortType
```

Comment: Please, show your code, cxf configuration and full stack trace

Comment: full stack trace: 100690 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO eg.etisalat.webdashboard.webservice.OMSWrapper - #getInstance(...): thrown com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException(A WebService annotation is not present on class: eg.com.etisalat.services.migration.v1.MigrationPortType) out of com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler#buildRuntimeModel[237] in 7s

Answer (score 0):

You need @WebService annotation just before the com.client.CustomerPortType. If you already have one and you still get this issue, try importing @WebService from javax.jws and then try importing it from jakarta.jws. I faced this same issue and changing jakarta to javax resolved it.